SWIG unable to find dependencies
I can't get SWIG to find the header files of included packages. I'm trying to build a project using CMake in Visual Studio, with packages installed using vcpkg. The CMake generation process appears to go fine, and I can find the packages in the build directory. Visual Studio's IntelliSence is also able to find the right file if I ctrl-click on an include statement. But when I try to build the prject, SWIG errors out at the first import statement as it can't find the referenced files.
I've tried many changes to my CMake file, but nothing really worked. The only thing that seemed to get me closer was manually adding hard references to every dependency and every dependency's dependency by using target_include_directories, but here I eventually also got stuck with a mountain of seeminly random errors mostly related to preprocessor macros in stock Windows include paths.
CMake file:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.21)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()

project ("AutoRiggerCpp")

include("C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
include(GenerateExportHeader)

set(SWIG_DIR "C:/Users/marro/Portable Programs/swigwin-4.3.0/Lib")
set(SWIG_EXECUTABLE "C:/Users/marro/Portable Programs/swigwin-4.3.0/swig.exe")  

find_package (SWIG REQUIRED)
include (UseSWIG)

set_property(SOURCE autorigger.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_source_files_properties(autorigger.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")

SWIG_ADD_LIBRARY(autorigger
                 TYPE SHARED
                 LANGUAGE CSharp
                 SOURCES autorigger.i
                )

find_package(libigl CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries( autorigger PRIVATE libigl Eigen3::Eigen)

# A desperate attempt which resulted in a long list of random errors
#target_include_directories( autorigger 
                                       #PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} 
                                       #PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} 
                                       #PRIVATE ${libigl_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                                       #PRIVATE ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                                       #PRIVATE "C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoriggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/vcpkg_installed/vcpkg/pkgs/libigl_x64-windows/include"
                                       #PRIVATE "C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoriggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/vcpkg_installed/vcpkg/pkgs/libigl_x64-windows/include/igl"
                                       #PRIVATE "C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoriggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/vcpkg_installed/vcpkg/pkgs/eigen3_x64-windows/include" 
                                       #PRIVATE "C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoriggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/vcpkg_installed/vcpkg/pkgs/eigen3_x64-windows/include/eigen3/Eigen" 
                                       #PRIVATE "C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/Eigen/src/Core/util"
                                       #PRIVATE "C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/vcpkg_installed/x64-windows/include/Eigen/src/Core"
                                       #PRIVATE "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.41.34120/include" 
                                       #PRIVATE "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22621.0/ucrt"
                                       
#)

#set_target_properties( autorigger
#    PROPERTIES
#    SWIG_USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES TRUE
#)

Build output:
>------ Build All started: Project: AutoRiggerCpp, Configuration: x64-release ------
  [1/3] Swig compile autorigger.i for csharp
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/autorigger.dir/autoriggerCSHARP_wrap.cxx autorigger.cs autoriggerPINVOKE.cs C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/CMakeFiles/autorigger.dir/autoriggerCSHARP_wrap.cxx C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/autorigger.cs C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/autoriggerPINVOKE.cs 
  C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\Users\marro\Etc\Cpp\AutoRiggerCpp\out\build\x64-release && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E make_directory C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/CMakeFiles/autorigger.dir C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/CMakeFiles/autorigger.dir && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E env "SWIG_LIB=C:/Users/marro/Portable Programs/swigwin-4.3.0/Lib" "C:/Users/marro/Portable Programs/swigwin-4.3.0/swig.exe" -csharp -includeall -outdir C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release -c++ -dllimport autorigger -o C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/out/build/x64-release/CMakeFiles/autorigger.dir/autoriggerCSHARP_wrap.cxx C:/Users/marro/Etc/Cpp/AutoRiggerCpp/autorigger.i"
C:\Users\marro\Etc\Cpp\AutoRiggerCpp\autorigger.h(10): error : Unable to find 'Eigen\Core'
  
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Build All failed.

